# Unable to resolve "../lib/util" from "node_modules\react-native-svg\elements\Text.js"

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I did some mess with the dependencies and installed the react-native-svg again even if expo already had. So i got the error while starting my application:

```
Unable to resolve "../lib/util" from "node_modules\react-native- 
svg\elements\Text.js"
```

No matter what my source code is.
I tried so far to remove and reinstall the expo-cli

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

I tried to remove manually the node_modules folder of the npm install on my computer and from my project folder

I tried to remove completely the project folder and to recreate a new project with the same name

But now even on clean project and after expo-cli reinstall I get the error above.

I'm lost in space

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Day saver

Comment: I am facing issue...Can you tell how could you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve discovered that if you accidentally install a dependency that already exists in Expo this is the simplest way to get things running again:

1. Close all terminals running `Expo`
2. Close the browser window running `Expo`
3. Clear the project you were working on from the `Expo` app on your device.
4. Delete your `package-lock.json`
5. Delete your `node_modules` folder
6. Remove the dependency/dependencies that you shouldn’t have added from your `package.json`
7. Run `npm i`
8. Restart `Expo` using `expo start -c`